# PHP SNMP Warning: SNMP::get(): No response from 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, snmp

I'm trying to get PHP SNMP to work on XAMPP PHP 7.1.9

I'm always getting this result: `Warning: SNMP::get(): No response from 127.0.0.1`

Here's what I did:

1. Enabled php_snmp.dll on php.ini
2. Installed net-snmp-5.5.0-2.x64
3. Added windows environment variable MIBDIRS with value C:\usr\share\snmp\mibs

Code I'm running to test:

```
<?php
    $session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_1, "127.0.0.1", "public");
    $sysdescr = $session->get("sysDescr.0");
    echo "$sysdescr\n";
    $session->close();
```

I'm new to this so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Step 2 won't give you a working SNMP agent on Windows, so your code won't get a response from 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Which version of windows is this?

Comment: I'm on windows10, though i guess i should point out that i also tried using php snmp on ubuntu and I got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the MIBDIRS path.

I followed php docs and it says:
`The Windows distribution of Net-SNMP contains support files for SNMP in the mibs directory. This directory should added to Windows' environment variables, as MIBDIRS, with the value being the full path to the mibs directory: e.g. c:\usr\mibs.`

Problem was I couldn't find `c:\usr\mibs` on my net-snmp installation so I used `C:\usr\share\snmp\mibs` instead.

**Solution:**

I tried using a device with snmp support instead of 127.0.0.1 and ran `snmpget` on cli and confirmed net-snmp installation actually works. I figured the problem must be with the path php is using to run snmp.

So I used `where snmpget` to check the command path then changed MIBDIRS environment value with the result which is `C:\usr\bin\snmpget.exe`